# T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error while trying to insert data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, insert

I've been trying to insert data into mysql with php but am getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE...

this is my insert file

```
<?php
    include_once 'include.php';
    include_once 'header.php';

    //$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $DBUser, $DBPasswd) 
    // or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    //echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

    $DBsubmit="INSERT INTO User (fname, lname, email, password, institution, expertise)   
               VALUES('$_POST['fname']', '$_POST['lname']', '$_POST['email']', '$_POST['password']', '$_POST['institution']', '$_POST['expertise']')";
    $result=mysql_query($DBsubmit)

    //echo "1 record added";

    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: [language.types.string.parsing.simple](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple)

Comment: You also forgot a semicolon here `$result=mysql_query($DBsubmit)` -> `$result=mysql_query($DBsubmit);`

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords, escape your incoming data or at least escape them, don't use old mysql_ functions.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

array access syntax inside of a string is different than outside.  Change to either:

```
{$_POST['fname']}
```

or

```
$_POST[fname]
```

You're also missing a semicolon on the `query` line.

Your code is also ***as vulnerable as possible***.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I like your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very vulnerable in SQL injection. I suggest using `mysql_real_escape_string` instead.

```
$DBsubmit=sprintf("INSERT INTO User (fname, lname, email, `password`, institution, expertise)
VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['institution']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expertise']));
```